# How to insert a value in an array using a for loop?

Tags: c++

I have an array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and i have to insert a value between them by increasing the array size like {1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,8,9} . How do i do it using 
a for loop?

Comment: You can't, you will have to create another array with larger size and copy/insert.

Comment: There are hundreds of possible answers to this. Voted to close because of this. Also, the OP really should try something first.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Do you know how to write a `for` loop? Do you know how to read elements from an array? Do you know how to assign elements of an array? It's not clear to me what the root of your question is.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ arrays are a fixed size and don't support growing the array.

Take a look at [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and its [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) method.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. But you could create a new array one item bigger and copy items across. Not efficent but would answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector`, something like:

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
vec.insert(vec.begin() + 4, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initiate array with the maximum number of elements array would contain.

```
int my[10];
```

Then iterate over the array to k position:

```
int k = 4;
for ( i = 0 ; i < sizeof(my) ; i++ )
    if ( k == i ) 
        //insert element and move rest of elements one to right ( shift them right )
```

How to shift?

```
int c = my[k];
for ( j = i+1 ; j < sizeof(my) ; j++ ) 
    {
    my[j] = c;
    c = my[j+1]
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(my)` is not what you expect. You mean `sizeof(my) / sizeof(*my)`...